Making chat feature in ASP.NET Core MVC and SignalR
I'm trying to add private chat, such as Direct Messages like on Instagram, to my ASP.NET Core MVC web app. And I'm having trouble in doing so.
At first I had problems with installing SignalR (it says usual version is legacy now), and by looking at some tutorials I made this:
My ChatHub.cs:
using AutoMapper;
using Hryhoriichuk.University.Instagram.Web.Data;
using Hryhoriichuk.University.Instagram.Web.Models;
using Hryhoriichuk.University.Instagram.Web.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hryhoriichuk.University.Instagram.Web.Hubs
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly AuthDbContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public ChatHub(AuthDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task SendPrivateMessage(string receiverName, string message)
        {
            var senderId = Context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            var receiver = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(receiverName);

            if (receiver != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(message?.Trim()))
            {
                var messageModel = new Message
                {
                    SenderId = senderId,
                    ReceiverId = receiver.Id,
                    Content = message,
                    Timestamp = DateTime.Now
                };

                _context.Messages.Add(messageModel);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                // Send message to both sender and receiver
                await Clients.Users(senderId, receiver.Id).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", messageModel);
            }
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            // Add the connected user's connection information to the database
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Context.User.Identity.Name);
            user.ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            // Find the user with the matching connection ID and update their connection ID to null
            var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);

            if (user != null)
            {
                user.ConnectionId = null;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
}

My Message model:
using Hryhoriichuk.University.Instagram.Web.Areas.Identity.Data;

namespace Hryhoriichuk.University.Instagram.Web.Models
{
    public class Message
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

        // Reference to the sender of the message
        public string SenderId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser FromUser { get; set; }

        // Reference to the receiver of the message
        public string ReceiverId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ToUser { get; set; }
    }
}

My MessageController:
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Hryhoriichuk.University.Instagram.Web.Data;
using Hryhoriichuk.University.Instagram.Web.Hubs;
using Hryhoriichuk.University.Instagram.Web.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Hryhoriichuk.University.Instagram.Web.Controllers
{
    public class MessageController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AuthDbContext _context;
        private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _hubContext;

        public MessageController(AuthDbContext context, IHubContext<ChatHub> hubContext)
        {
            _context = context;
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Message>> Get(int id)
        {
            var message = await _context.Messages.FindAsync(id);

            if (message == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(message);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Message>> Create(Message message)
        {
            var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);

            if (user == null)
                return BadRequest("User not found");

            message.Content = Regex.Replace(message.Content, @"<.*?>", string.Empty);
            message.FromUser = user;
            message.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;

            _context.Messages.Add(message);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            // Broadcast the message
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("newMessage", message);

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id = message.Id }, message);
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            var message = await _context.Messages
                .Include(u => u.FromUser)
                .Where(m => m.Id == id && m.FromUser.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (message == null)
                return NotFound();

            _context.Messages.Remove(message);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("removeChatMessage", message.Id);

            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpGet("Chat")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Chat()
        {
            // Get the messages for the chat
            var messages = await _context.Messages
                .Include(m => m.FromUser)
                .OrderBy(m => m.Timestamp)
                .ToListAsync();

            return View(messages);
        }
    }
}

I created Startup.cs and that's how it looks:
using Hryhoriichuk.University.Instagram.Web.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

namespace Hryhoriichuk.University.Instagram.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSignalR();
            // Other service configurations
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            // Other app configurations

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
                // Other endpoints mapping
            });
        }
    }
}


And this is what I get on my website:

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but there are no tutorials on how to implement SignalR individual chat based on User Identity ASP.NET Core MVC. How can I do this?

Show us your ConfigureServices method.

I have updated the post and added how my Startup.cs looks

…and your Profram.Main method
